# items added to c# listbox with lb_addstring do not affect items.count

Tags: c#, listbox

A C# WinForms app has a ListBox on the form. The ListBox window handle is passed to a legacy Win32 DLL that uses SendMessage(hWnd,LB_ADDSTRING...) to add items to the list box. These strings appear in the listbox at runtime, however the listbox.Items.Count is 0, and one cannot access individual items using listbox.Items[x].ToString()

What do you need to do in the C# app to have it realize that those strings are in its list and therefore should be reflected in Items.Count, as well as accessible using Items[x] ?

Comment: Why do you want to add items that way.  You probably know that the right way to do it is to call listbox.Items.Add(string);

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of `ListBox`, override `WndProc`, listen for `LB_ADDSTRING` messages (value = 0x180), prevent those messages from being handled normally and instead add the data they contain to the `Items` collection. Haven't tested this code but it should be close enough to what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class LegacyListBox : ListBox
{
    private const int LB_ADDSTRING = 0x180;

    public LegacyListBox() { }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == LB_ADDSTRING)
        {
            Items.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(m.LParam));

            // prevent base class from handling this message
            return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```